# Center element vertically and new element should be added in new line

Tags: html, css

Center element vertically and new element should be added in the next line (without using `<br/>`)

```
.parent { 
    position: relative;
    background: #FF0000;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
.children { 
    background: #000;
    width: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Jsfiddle is in here: http://jsfiddle.net/richersoon/m8kp92yL/5/

Result should be something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @cosmoonot updated with jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify `.parent` to have a `height:auto;` to accommodate the height of each `.children` element and `padding:20px 0;` was added to show 20px worth of red background above the first child.

In your `.children` css `display:inline-block` was removed and `margin: 0 auto` allows each child to center within `.parent` element, after each child element `margin-bottom:5px;` displays the 5px gap.

```css
.parent { 
    position: relative;
    background: #FF0000;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:20px 0px;    
    }
.children { 
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:5px;    
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, the parent's width should be 100%

Comment: Children's width should not 100%, it can be smaller than 30%  of parents width

Comment: @richersoon I see. k, revised, now width of children is 200px and they auto centered to the parent.

Comment: It works, but it would be nicer if you can you point out the code that make it work

Comment: @richersoon check out the revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would make things easy by changing the boxes to `display: flex;` and making the `.parent` class `height: auto;` then adding the appropriate margins and padding like so.

```css
.parent { 
     position: relative;
     background: #FF0000;
     text-align: left;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     padding: 5px;
}
.children { 
     background: #000;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     display: flex; 
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```